# Objective-C running loop in background while keeping UI functional?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

How can I run a loop in the background such as:

```
while(1==1){
  NSLog(@"hello");
}
```

while being able to detect a button click such as:

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    //do something
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use GCD to run the code on a background thread.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Read Apple's [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) and maybe [Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i).

The first of these will introduce you to *operation queues* (`NSOperation`) and *dispatch queues* (GCD), the second to threads (`NSThread` & Posix).

If after reading the guide you are unsure which of the approaches to take, at least for the situation you raise above, consider GCD first and then operation queues.

If you get stuck implementing your solution ask a new question, showing your code and explaining your issues. Somebody will undoubtedly help you out.

HTH